# Search sub arrays for specific key

Tags: php, arrays

What's the most efficient way to search an array element's sub arrays to check the value of a specific key? For example, given the following array, where I want to check both subarrays "msg" value, and if either is populated, return a boolean result:

```
[TGMN02] => Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 93143
                    [msg] => 
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 24876
                    [msg] => 
                )
        )
```

What I have at the moment is simply looping through and checking, which feels quite clunky.

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/ / show us some real code...

Comment: Looping of one form or another is the way to do it...

Comment: Some users marked this as a duplicate, but the "How to search by key=>value in a multidimensional array in PHP" question that it's linked to is a very different type of problem (a deeply nested array, requiring a recursive solution).  This question appears to be asking for a simple loop, checking the sub-elements only one level deep.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about "most" efficient but this won't necessarily have to iterate through the whole array as it breaks the loop on the first value found, so technically more efficient.

```
 function hasMsg($a){
   foreach($a as $b)
     if(!empty($b['msg'])) return true;
   return false;
 }
```

---

Okay... since some *meager* comments weren't accompanied by alternative suggestions - you could try using some PHP>5.3 - I really can't see how it would be any *more efficient* though - it must still loop through the array at some level (but I'm not 100% sure on the inner workings of the PHP interpreter - perhaps there is some internal magic that could speed things up), so this is probably purely aesthetic:

```
$hasMsg = !!(count(array_filter($a,function($b){ return !empty($b['msg']); })));
```

... if anything less efficient.  **There's nothing wrong with "looping" through an array** - it's a tried and tested language construct that's been around since the dawn of digital time (almost).

Comment: You're just "looping through and checking". You've recreated the answer that OP already says they have and not answered the question they actually asked.

Comment: *"What I have at the moment is simply looping through and checking, which feels quite clunky."*

Comment: Regardless of it "feeling clunky", this is as good a solution as exists for this particular problem in PHP.

Answer (score -1):

First write some custom func and then try to use it with array_walk_recursive(array &$input , callable $funcname [, mixed $userdata = NULL ]) function. [Php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php).